# How to list all reoccurrence meetings from calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to list all events in my calendar (or in a time frame), it works well if they are single instance events. But I was not able to list all meetings set as reoccorruence meetings for 10 weeks, for instance.

Tried the follow apis:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
GET /me/events/{id}/instances?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}

GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events/{id}/instances?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}

GET /groups/{id}/events/{id}/instances?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

What {id} is it? I don't want to inform anything else then the calendar, it seems a meeting id. There is no documentation about it.

Comment: The IDs refer to the resource you are interacting with. In the first request, it would be an event id. In the second, it would be a user Id in the first place, then an event Id in the second. For the last one it would be a group Id, then an event id

Comment: Thank you bwest, this is what I thought, but I don't have any event id to inform. 

I would like to have is something like this API: 

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location

It returns all single events in my calendar. I need all reoccurrence events (or with multiple instances)